# Замена символов на изображения

Tags: php

Как сделать замену символьных эмодзи `:)` на изображения `<img src="smiles/aa.gif" alt=":)">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `str_replace` - ищет в переменной, которую ей передали, значение и меняет его на то, которое было дано в другом аргументе...

Статья про неё из официальной документации :) :

`str_replace` — Заменяет строку поиска на строку замены

Описание
`mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int $&count ] )`

Эта функция возвращает строку или массив `subject`, в котором все вхождения `search` заменены на `replace`. Если не нужны сложные правила поиска/замены, использование этой функции предпочтительнее `ereg_replace()` или `preg_replace()`.

С версии PHP 4.0.5, любой аргумент `str_replace()` может быть массивом.

Внимание
 
В версиях младше 4.3.3 эта функция содержит ошибку при одновременной передаче массивов в аргументах `search` и `replace`. Ошибка заключается в том, что пустые элементы массива `search` пропускались без перемещения к следующему элементу массива `replace`. Эта ошибка была исправлена в PHP 4.3.3. Если ваши скрипты использовали эту ошибку, то в них нужно удалить пустые элементы из массива search перед вызовом этой функции.

Если `subject` - массив, поиск и замена производится в каждом элементе этого массива, и возвращается также массив.

Если и `search`, и `replace` - массивы, то `str_replace()` использует все значения массива `search` и соответствующие значения массива `replace` для поиска и замены в `subject`. Если в массиве `replace` меньше элементов, чем в `search`, в качестве строки замены для оставшихся значений будет использована пустая строка. Если `search` - массив, а `replace` - строка, то `replace` будет использована как строка замены для каждого элемента массива `search`.

Примеры использования `str_replace()`

```
<?php
// присваивает <body text='black'>
$bodytag = str_replace("%body%", "black", "<body text='%body%'>");

// присваивает: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");

// присваивает: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);

// начиная с версии 5.0.0 доступен аргумент count
$str = str_replace("ll", "", "good golly miss molly!", $count);
echo $count; // 2

?>
```

Comment: Плюсиг и ответ принять не забудь - Всегда рад помочь :)

Answer (score 0):

Действительно можно воспользоваться **str_replace**. 
Но, есть одно но. Как я понял, ваши сообщения помещаются в БД (хотя может я и ошибаюсь). В таком случае, наверное, логичнее менять ваши текстовые смайлы на графические не в момент занесения информации в базу, а производить замену в момент выборки данных из БД и вывода их на страницу.

Comment: Эм возможно - Но как это помешает ему использовать str_replace ? :) Некоректный ответ...

Comment: Я не говорю, что это помешает. Просто советую автору вопроса над этим задуматься

Comment: я так понял Вы пишите чат. Идея записывать все в один и тот же файл не слишком хороша по многим причинам:

1. Когда-то сообщений будет сильно много - соответственно размер Вашего файла будет большим и это повлияет на скорость загрузки страницы
2. во-вторых это у Вас будет похоже не на чат, а на систему комментирования
3. Если Вы планируете развивать свой чат, то Вам желательно все же использовать базу. Это удобно и практично для развития функциональности чата (приват и др.)
4. Чат все-таки предполагает общение в режиме реального времени

Comment: Вот с этим согласен...